# Unity3D Засвет далеких объектов

Tags: unity3d

Создал поле кубов, но на большой дистанции они становятся белыми, это как то связано с цветами текстуры, которую я использую.
как можно это отключить?

[image: Дальние кубы становятся белыми]

[image: Текстура куба]

Comment: это стандартный шейдер?

Comment: пост процессинг эффектов на камере нет?

Comment: все стандартное, ничего не добавлял

Comment: Не может ли это быть эффект от тумана? Попробуйте отключить Туман, если он включен. В коде можно так: `RenderSettings.fog = false`